# Set Width / Height jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, height, width

Im a bit new to jQuery UI.

I have:

```
// dialog profile options
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('This dialog will show every time!')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                title: 'Basic Dialog'
            });

        $('#setAccountSettings').click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
            return false;
        });
});
```

How do I set `minWidth` to 600 and `minHeight` to 200? Sorry Im somewhat new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set minHeight and minWidth as options when you init the dialog

```
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            title: 'Basic Dialog',
            minWidth: 600,
            minHeight: 200

        });
```

You can read more about available options on http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for.